# Get products list by url key in Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am a newbie in php and I want to display a list of products on my custom page. Is there a way i can use the URL KEY to get their ids? Something like

> example.com/custom?id=1200&1301

This way on my custom page will display the two products with id 1200 and id 1301.
It`s like using woocommerce shortcode where you can display the products by ids.

> [products id="1200, 1301" orderby="title" order="desc"]

But now i want to get the ids from the url key, making this page a dynamic one!

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is off the cuff, but if you created a page in WP with the slug "custom", then created it's own template page...

Then you could pull in the value of `$ids = $_GET['id']`, which might be "1200,1301"...

Now you'd have to do some sanitizing of the values in $ids but then:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[products id="{$ids}" orderby="title" order="desc"]" );
```